# Is there anyway possible to make HTML5 Video run only off of Wifi/Internet?

Tags: html, video, wifi

Is there any way possible to make HTML Video run off of internet, and buffer when the internet connection is weak, or low, for example, the YouTube Player, The basic idea is to chop video, and buffer it before the client clicks play, can this be based on internet connection and wifi? I will do anyway possible to implement this feature!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, the video element does most of the buffering in the background (depending on the internet connection), and is usually quite good at it. From experience, it is more time-efficient as a developer to try to optimize the size/quality of the streaming video (using tools like Handbrake) rather than try to alter buffering depending on network variables.

That being said, if you are mainly targeting mobile devices, you could could use the experimental [Network Information API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Network_Information_API) to get info in Javascript what kind of mobile connection the device is using, and then direct them to a different (low quality) version of the video if they are using 3g or slower.

Alternatively, if you just want the video to start preloading (not playing) as soon as the page loads, have a look at the [preload feature on the html video element](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_preload.asp).